# If $P$ is true then not $Q$

Tags: logic

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

"If this sentence is true then tomorrow will not rain".

1. tomorrow will rain
2. tomorrow will not rain
3. the sentence is a paradox

What I thought is:

$P \Rightarrow \lnot Q$

$¬P \lor ¬Q$

So the result is: EITHER the sentence is false OR tomorrow is not raining.
Then the answer should be the number 1. Am I right?

Comment: The sentence refers to itself. Such problems are notoriously difficult to analyze, and cannot be written in the propositional calculus. Are you sure you typed the problem correctly?

Comment: Yes, there's only the text I wrote above on the paper :)

Comment: It might help if you would acknowledge previous things from the literature of very much the same flavor, such as “This sentence is false.” Anyway, my take is that the nature of the resolution of what you have proposed is independent of the negation within it. That is, “If this statement is true then it will rain tomorrow.” has the same type of resolution as the statement you propose.

Comment: It seems to me that "This sentence is true" is meaningless nonsense. What then are we to make of the statement $P\implies Q$ where $P$ is meaningless nonsense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, this is interesting. As you've noted, "this sentence" takes the form $P \Rightarrow \lnot Q$, where

$P$: This sentence is true

$Q$: Tomorrow will rain.

Suppose "this sentence is false". Then $P \Rightarrow \lnot Q$ is false. The only way that can happen is if $P$ is true and $\lnot Q$ is false. But $P$ is "This sentence is true", and so we have a contradiction.

Hence, it cannot be the case "that this sentence is false". Thus, "this sentence is true", from which (and Modus Ponens) we derive $\lnot Q$, and so tomorrow will not rain.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following related sentence: "If this statement is true, then I am a space alien."

On the one hand, if the statement is true, then it is true - so I am a space alien.

On the other hand, if it is false, then - since it is of the form "$A\implies B$" - the hypothesis must be true and the conclusion false. But, if the hypothesis is true, then the statement is true (since that's the hypothesis!), so the statement must be true.

Note that this applies to **all** statements of the form "If I am true, then [???]." In particular, we can use such statements to "prove" anything we want: to prove $P$, analyze the statement "If this statement is true, then $P$."

(As to the choices: is this statement a paradox? It depends what you mean by that. Certainly its *syntactic form* allows us to introduce paradoxes . . . The intended answer is 2, I guess, but personally I would say 3.)

---

So what does this tell us? Well, basically it says that any formal system broad enough to allow both self-referentiality and truth predicates is paradoxical.

One consequence of this is that no consistent classical theory can do both these things; this is, in fact, basically how one proves Tarski's undefinability theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski's_undefinability_theorem.